# Appium scrollto()/hidekeyboard() methods are not working with client jar 3.3.0/3.4.0 in iphone

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I have tried most of the possible method(java script/touchaction) but not able to scroll
if any one have solution please help me, thanks

Comment: you need top update your post with the code you tried .. other wise query will be flag soon and closed as off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int x = size.width / 2;
int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.75);
int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
driver.swipe(x, starty, x, endy, 1000);
```

For more details check below post:
[Click Here](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2016/03/road-to-scroll-application-using-appium.html)